# Execute Process concurently

Tags: c++, c, linux, parallel-processing, fork

my program takes range from user.then it creates 3 process and execute them one by one
but I want that all process run concurrently.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    void function();
    cin>>range;
cin>>process;
    int main() {
    int range = 1000;
    int i;
    int pid;
    int pid1;
    for(i = 0; i < ; i++) {
    pid1 = fork();
    }
    if(pid1==0) {
    pid = getpid();
    printf("The process id is: %d\n", pid);
    function(range); 
    }
    else {
    wait(0); 
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you not make three different threads and fork from them?

Comment: You want 3 processes? Or 8?

Comment: if you wait(NULL) you are lauching the process one by one

Comment: well its not issue whether it is 3 or 8 main issue is to run them concurrently

Comment: So, don't call `wait` before starting the next one!

Comment: @Beta What is magical about 8?

Comment: @pranitkothari: it's 2^3.

Comment: @Alexis then what shouldi do in that case

Comment: @UsmanNazir remove the wait function

Comment: @pranitkothari: The for-loop will continue in the forked process, so they create further copies of itself. It would be a good idea to place a `break` in the `if (pid1 == 0)` branch.

Comment: As you say, the issue is not whether there are 3 or 8. The issue is whether you know how many there are, or understand what these commands do, and whether you are willing to learn. If you don't care whether your code works correctly or not, then we can't help you.

Comment: @MatsPetersson i have removed wait but still no progress

Comment: @Beta well i know that if for loop is for(int i=0;i<3) then it makes 2^3 process but my problem is that i want my process run my all process concurrently.

Comment: Is the code you posted really what you are using? What's with the `cin >> range` in the middle of the code? How do you KNOW it doesn't do what you want, since the code appears to not show anything?

Comment: @Mats Petersson well my main code is to take user range for a function to calculate prime number.like that suppose user give                                  range=1000; and number of process=5;                                   the i have to calulate prime number from                                0-200 from process 1                                                    201-400 from 2 and so on                                                 all process should run concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as others have mentioned, you are not forking 3 processes, you are forking 8. Fix that like this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
     pid1 = fork();
     if (pid1 == 0) break;
 }
```

Then, all 4 processes *are* running in parallel. Depending on what `function` does, it may be hard to see this, though - it may finish too quickly. So try this:

```
if (pid1 == 0) {
   printf("pid=%d\n", getpid());
   sleep(5);
   printf("done sleep %d\n", getpid());
} else {
   wait(0);
}
```

You should three printouts of "pid=XX", then a delay of about 5 seconds, then "done sleep XX".

Comment: its not working as first it print id of all process latter it prints sleep p1 then p2 and then p3

Comment: that *is* working. Use your watch and time it. Does it take 5 seconds, or 15 seconds? If it's 15 seconds, then it's not concurrent. But if it's only 5, then it means all three processes executed their "sleep(5)" concurrently.

Comment: btw - what did you expect to see? What does "concurrent" mean to you?

Comment: well i wana see that suppose i create 3 process first run and print prime number mean while second run and print its out put the third then again first process print remaining output and so on.but in my case it print first full output of first process then second then then third i am confused...:/

Comment: and yes it takes five second as you said . i am getting little bit